# Individual class option for radio buttons

Tags: forms, class, cakephp, radio-button, cakephp-2.3

Is there an individual class option for radio buttons in Cake 2.x?

In my opinion the logical approach would be like:

```
<div class="input radio required">
    <?php 
        $options = array(
            array('1' => 'Kuchen', 'class' => 'cake'),
            array('2' => 'Kekse', 'class' => 'biscuits'),
            array('3' => 'Eis', 'class' => 'iceCream'),
        );
        $attributes = array(
            'legend' => false,
            'default' => '1'
        );
        echo $this->Form->radio('INCOMETYPE', $options, $attributes);
    ?>
</div>
```

But that doesn´t work. I hope you can help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could extend FormHelper to add implement this functionality if you intend to use it elsewhere. If it's a one off, you might be better to produce the markup by hand. Use the code produced by $this->Form->radio to give you a start.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem with doing it by hand is the validator not remembering the selected values. Would it be a good approach to add classes with jquery on document ready? Or is that bad coding? Well, it´s really a one off.